# python 2.7 make txt file containing a datalist

Tags: python, file, printing, output

I'm a total beginner in programming and even more with Python (I can make some basic things in c++...)

I am working on a code that a friend made for me a while ago and I'd like to store its output in a file, i thought a `.txt` file would be perfect for what I want to do.

You will find 2 codes below,

the 1st one works but only prints the data in the interactive window of pythonwin (I'm using windows 7 and python 2.7).

It prints something like that, which is useful data for my project:

```
thrown out: bTUD, K2, MAG B, K1C, K1B, K1A, XTC64 II, REF , LBK, MAG C
1   1   : ['PINKwA', 'GB', 'PINK', 'TUwA'] [ 0.23994351  0.61419796  0.00956974  0.1362888 ] tet_i 66
1   2   : ['PINKwA', 'GB', 'PINK', 'TUwA'] [ 0.23816363  0.61917833  0.01219634  0.13046169] tet_i 66
1   3   : ['PINKwA', 'GB', 'PINK', 'TUwA'] [ 0.23638376  0.6241587   0.01482295  0.12463459] tet_i 66
1   4   : ['PINKwA', 'GB', 'PINK', 'TUwA'] [ 0.23460388  0.62913907  0.01744955  0.11880749] tet_i 66
1   5   : ['PINKwA', 'GB', 'PINK', 'TUwA'] [ 0.23282401  0.63411944  0.02007616  0.11298039] tet_i 66
...etc.
```

The 2nd code is my attempt to use the functions `output` and `output.write` but it doesn't works at all! I am missing basic language skills in python and I guess that's why I cannot figure out the solution.

1st code (print function OK)

```
import tetgen, geometry
from pprint import pprint
import random, csv
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint

all_colors = [(name, float(X), float(Y), float(Z))
              for name, X, Y, Z in csv.reader(open('colors.csv'))]

# background is marked SUPPORT
support_i = [i for i, color in enumerate(all_colors) if color[0] == 'SUPPORT']
if len(support_i)>0:
    support = np.array(all_colors[support_i[0]][1:])
    del all_colors[support_i[0]]
else:
    support = None

tg, hull_i = geometry.tetgen_of_hull([(X,Y,Z) for name, X, Y, Z in all_colors])
colors = [all_colors[i] for i in hull_i]

print ("thrown out: "
       + ", ".join(set(zip(*all_colors)[0]).difference(zip(*colors)[0])))

targets = [(name, float(X), float(Y), float(Z), float(BG))
           for name, X, Y, Z, BG in csv.reader(open('targets.csv'))]

for target in targets:
    name, X, Y, Z, BG = target

    target_point = support + (np.array([X,Y,Z]) - support)/(1-BG)

    tet_i, bcoords = geometry.containing_tet(tg, target_point)

    if tet_i == None:
        print "out"
        # not in gamut
    else:
        names = [colors[i][0] for i in tg.tets[tet_i]]
        print "%s:" % target[0], names, bcoords, "tet_i", tet_i
```

EDIT: the code belows works but exports only one line of data in the file

```
for target in targets:
    name, X, Y, Z, BG = target

    target_point = support + (np.array([X,Y,Z]) - support)/(1-BG)

    tet_i, bcoords = geometry.containing_tet(tg, target_point)


if tet_i == None:
    output = open('output.txt','a')
    output.write(str(target[0]))    

else:
    output = open('output.txt','a')
    names = [colors[i][0] for i in tg.tets[tet_i]]
    output.write(str(target[0]))
    output.write(str(names))
    output.write(str(bcoords))
```

Could you please help me finding out how to write that data into a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to user2571168's solution, I believe `output.write()` expects a string, so try converting them using `str()`. For example,

```
output.write(str(names))
```

EDIT:

This may or may not fix your problem but you should close the file when you are finished writing to it. For example:

```
if tet_i == None:
    output = open('output.txt','a')
    output.write(str(target[0]))
    output.close()

else:
    output = open('output.txt','a')
    names = [colors[i][0] for i in tg.tets[tet_i]]
    output.write(str(target[0]))
    output.write(str(names))
    output.write(str(bcoords))
    output.close()
```

Note the addition of both calls to `output.close()`. Let me know after this if your problem still persists.

Comment: thanks! that's one problem solved, now it works but seems like the file contains only the last iteration of the process, and that it has overwritten the previous data. I put an EDIT on the msg above, any idea what's wrong with the code now?

Comment: thanks, that works now: this `output = open('output.txt','a')` had to be placed before `if tet_i == None:` and because of your tip about closing the file, I avoid another error!

Answer (score 1):

When you open your file, I recommend using `'a'` as the second parameter in your case so that the file will always be appended too, instead of overwritten every time you call the write method. 
You said in the begingin to wanted a `.txt` file, so why don't you use one?

`output = open('output.txt','a')`

Secondly, the write method in a file can only take one input. Call the write method every time you want to add something to it. In your case do this:

```
    output.write(target[0])
    output.write(names)
    output.write(bcoords)
    output.write(tet_i)
```

EDIT: Also, anything that you put into a file needs to be a string. You can use the `str()` function to convert it into a string.

Comment: Thanks, looks like the solution, however I get an error like this: `TypeError: expected a character buffer object`

Comment: So, anything that you write in your file must be a string. If it is not a string, you can easily make it so using `str(number)`
And then if you want to read that number back from the file you can use the `int()` or `float()` inbuilt functions in python to convert them into their correct format.

Comment: Thank you, that's better already. The file's created, however it contains only one line...the last one, like if all the other were overwritten, could you please check the msg edit above? Thanks